# CakePHP; how to make find conditions dependent upon foreign key of $id parameter

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements

I'm new to programming so please forgive me if this is a noob question!

I'm using Cake to build a blog, with the models **users** and **entries**.

I have a View page for the blog entries and I would like to add a list with all the other entries that its creator has written to it.

So what I need is for the find function in my entries controller to display only the entries with the same number as the foreign key "user_id" of the currently viewed entry.

Currently, in the entries controller I have added the following:

```
    $this->set('entries',
        $this->Entry->find('all', array(
            'conditions'=>array('Entry.user_id' => $id)
            )
        )
    );
```

So it takes the parameter of the view action, rather than its foreign key, which isn't quite what I want.

But the problem is that I just can't think of how to get the foreign key...

Hope you can help me out with that, thanks.

Comment: this data should be available to you by default if you've set up associations correctly (`entries belongsTo users` and `users hasMany entries`. have you adjusted `$this->recursive` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function view($id = null){
   if(!$id)$this->redirect(/*somewhere*/);
   $entry = $this->Entry->read(null,$id);
   $entries = $this->Entry->find('all', array(
            'conditions'=>array('Entry.user_id' => $entry['Entry']['user_id')
            )
        );
   $this->set(compact('entry','entries'));
}
```

You will need a certain degree of familiarity of Cake (don't just blindly copy the code). Hopefully the above code will point you to the right direction.

Comment: Anh Pham, that was just what I needed!! Looking at it now, I should have been able to think of that myself, but I guess I just lack the experience... ^^'

Also, I noticed how you "forgot" that square bracket on purpose XD ! Again, thanks so much for the help!